# sybase insert from another database in same server

Tags: insert, sybase

i am trying to get all extra data from one data base and trying to insert into another. 
But i want to omit the column name and  am trying to make only the table name as hard coded to achieve this. But we have some fields which are system generated in a table like an id which is not that necessary a data but still will create a integrity issue.  How can i do a insert of just the wanna be details omitting those above columns, the names of the columns to omit also changes.. I can't do a total insert, just the addition of some extra data.

so far i have come to this.

```
while 1=1
begin
if exists(select 1 from db1.table1 not in (select * from db2.table1)
begin
insert into db2.table1 (columns) select (columns) from db1.table1
end
if(rowCount=0)
break
end
```

please advise how i can optimize this  to get the least possible hard coding 
Have left the pk part intentionally, as
 the query being big.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to something like:

```
insert into TAB
select * from TAB2
```

or

```
insert into TAB
select col1,col2 from TAB2
```

or

```
insert into TAB (col1,col2)
select * from TAB2
```

where TAB1 and TAB2 have different count or type of columns it's  not possible, because it will generate an error.